# Set Cover Problem

Tags: algorithms

Show that, for any integer `n` that is a power of `2`, there is an instance of the Set Cover problem with the following properties:

i. There are `n` elements in the base set.

ii. The optimal cover uses just two sets.

iii. The greedy algorithm picks at least `(log n) - 1` sets.

Thus the approximation ratio we derived for the greedy algorithm is tight (up to a constant
factor).

I am having trouble solving this question. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose that I had such an instance of the Set Cover problem for $n = 2^k$. How could I use that instance to construct one where $n = 2^{k+1}$?